# Community ad rendering bug in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm having a problem rendering the community ads on Firefox 5.0.1, where they are displayed side-by-side instead of vertically:

[image: Bug in rendering community ad: ads displayed side-by-side rather than vertically]

This problem occurs often under Firefox, but not under Internet Explorer 9.  I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium x64.  Can someone fix this?

**Edit:** The bug only occurs when a non-Stack Exchange ad and the newsletter ad are adjacent to each other as rendered on Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed float: left as suggested.  This will go out with the next deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I fired up Firefox and browsed around the site for quite a while, and I could never repro this...

Comment: **Found something:** Removing the `float: left` CSS attribute from `.ad-container` solves this for me.

Comment: This only happens in the very specific case where the newsletter is placed right after a Super User community ad, I noticed that on the other ads the `float:left` is absent and have verified that removing the `float:left` in the stable versions of other browsers does not break anything. In order to see it you might need to be logged in and refresh the cache a few times...